# Environement variables size limit beanstalk node.js

Tags: node.js, security, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an aws beanstalk instance with node.js where the limit for the size of the .env is 4096 bytes. I need more than that, there's no way i can fit all the secret keys in this space. Is there a way to load .env in another way or get it from a remote server ?